# Group Order Line Items in Product Bundles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleProducts 
(
    ProductId INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO SampleProducts 
VALUES (1, 'Product 1'), (2, 'Product 2'), (3, 'Product 3'),
       (4, 'Product 4')

CREATE TABLE Bundle  
(
    BundleId INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO Bundle 
VALUES (1, 'Bundle 1'), (2, 'Bundle 2')

CREATE TABLE BundleProduct  
(
    BundleId INT,
    ProductId INT
)

INSERT INTO BundleProduct 
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)

CREATE TABLE SaleOrder 
(
    OrderId INT,
    OrderNumber NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO SaleOrder 
VALUES (1, 'SO0001'), (2, 'SO0002'), (3, 'SO0003')

CREATE TABLE SaleOrderLine 
(
    OrderLineId INT,
    OrderId     INT,
    ProductId   INT
)

INSERT INTO SaleOrderLine 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), 
       (4, 3, 3), (5, 3, 4)
```

I need to find orders where customers purchase products that could be grouped in a bundle. For example, in order `SO0001`, products 1 and 2 were sold, this order must be in the result. In `SO0002` only were sold Product 1. SO0003 contains products from `Bundle2`. This is the set result I need to get:

**Result**

```
| OrderId | BundleId |
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    |
|    3    |     2    |
```

How can I get the result?

Answer (score 1):

This query joins the SaleOrderLines with the Bundles to count the distinct products from each SaleOrder that are contained in a specific Bundle. If this number is the total number of products in that Bundle, we have a match:

```sql
WITH
  BundleProductCount (BundleID, ProductCount) AS (
    SELECT BundleId, COUNT(ProductId)
    FROM BundleProduct
    GROUP BY BundleId
  ),
  OrderBundleProductCount (OrderId, BundleId, ProductCount) AS (
    SELECT sol.OrderId, bp.BundleId, COUNT(DISTINCT sol.ProductId)
    FROM SaleOrderLine sol
      INNER JOIN BundleProduct bp ON sol.ProductId = bp.ProductId
    GROUP BY sol.OrderId, bp.BundleId
  )
SELECT ob.OrderId, ob.BundleId
FROM OrderBundleProductCount ob
  INNER JOIN BundleProductCount b ON ob.BundleID = b.BundleID
WHERE ob.ProductCount = b.ProductCount;
```

**Added:**

A shorter version of what you came up with yourself, respecting products appearing multiple times on the same order:

```
SELECT l.OrderId, bp.BundleId
FROM SaleOrderLine l
  INNER JOIN BundleProduct bp ON l.ProductId = bp.ProductId
GROUP BY l.OrderId, bp.BundleId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.ProductId) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM BundleProduct
    WHERE BundleId = bp.BundleId
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer put me on the right direction. Please check my answer, the idea is the same, but I made use of HAVING instead of a Common Table Expression.

Comment: Seen it, and it is even faster than mine, but also your query can be optimized, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Yes, thats a good optimization, but as I commented there is no way of a product appears multiple times in the order. Its a businnes rule from customer.

Comment: @antonio_mg As you didn't explicitly confirm, can an item be present in more than one group?

Comment: At the moment, Antonio seems to want all "feasible" bundles for an order. If we were to look at an "optimal" way to split an order into bundles (if possible), we would have arrived at a "knapsack problem" which is know to be *hard* to solve.

Comment: @MatBailie no at this moment

Answer (score 1):

This is my best attempt to solve this problem:

```
SELECT o.[OrderId], bp.[BundleId]
FROM [SaleOrder] o
INNER JOIN [SaleOrderLine] l ON l.[OrderId] = o.[OrderId]
INNER JOIN [SampleProducts] p ON p.[ProductId] = l.[ProductId]
INNER JOIN [BundleProduct] bp ON bp.[ProductId] = l.[ProductId]
GROUP BY o.[OrderId], bp.[BundleId]
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Bundle] b
    INNER JOIN [BundleProduct] bp2 ON bp.[BundleId] = b.[BundleId]
    WHERE bp2.[BundleId] = bp.[BundleId]
    GROUP BY b.[BundleId]
    )
```

First I join Sale Order Lines with Bundle Products, group them and then count them and compare against the number of Products in Bundle, if the result is equal, it means that a bundle can be created. The idea is similar to the solution proposed by Wolfgang Kais, but without the use of Common Table Expressions

*** Update

This is the new query removing unnecesary joins. Thank you @MatBailie

```
SELECT l.[OrderId], bp.[BundleId]
FROM [SaleOrderLine] l
INNER JOIN [BundleProduct] bp ON bp.[ProductId] = l.[ProductId]
GROUP BY l.[OrderId], bp.[BundleId]
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [BundleProduct] bp2
    WHERE bp2.[BundleId] = bp.[BundleId]
    GROUP BY bp2.[BundleId]
    )
```

Comment: Can an order contain the same item multiple times? If so, this method didn't distinguish between buying 1 and 2 (bundle 1) and buying 1 and 1.  Also, what should happen if an order is made for items 1,2,3?  Is bundle 1?  Or, if they buy 1,1,2,2 is that bundle 1 twice? And if they buy 1,2,3,4,5 is that bundle 1 And bundle 2 with Item 5 left over? Can bundles ever overlap? (bundle 3 = items 4,5,6, bundle 4 = items 6,7,8) Can bundle ever contain multiple copies of the same item? (bundle 5 = items 9,9,9, for a buy two get one free)

Comment: No, same item can't be in the order multiple times. If an order is made for items 1,2,3 is bundle 1, product 3 needs to be sell with product 4 to be sell as bundle.  If they buy 1,2,3,4,5 is that bundle 1 and bundle 2 with Item 5 left over as you say.

Comment: Your sub query didn't need to join on Bundle, you can group by bp2.bundle_id.  Other than that, it seems fine.  But, it didn't show "left over" items, such as item 5 if ordering 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Your main query also doesn't need to join on the products table, or the sale order table. All of the columns you're using appear in the other tables.

Comment: @antonio_mg This would be inefficient, since you have 4 explicit joins and fifth by using subquery in such way. My solution provide query with much less `JOIN`s. If you want to get good performance as well, you might want to see my answer :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I tested it, in fact performance is pretty much already the same http://i64.tinypic.com/16h66o0.jpg

Comment: I both agree and disagree. There are redundant joins, and fir performance they should be removed. Functionally, however, this query can match a sale of 1,2,3,4 to bundles 1 and 2, the string aggregation method can not. Then both methods involve full table scans, but this one only joins by ids, the other by strings, I would exist this answer (with the redundant joins removed) to be faster.  Once indexes are added, this will be significantly faster, and scale well on large datasets.

Comment: Finally, there's no need to `GROUP BY bp2.[BundleId]` in the subquery, as only one bundle at a time is looked at.

Answer (score 0):

`Row_Number` is the key function here. The query can be written as:

```
select distinct
OrderId , 
BundleId
From  
(
select SO.OrderId,B.BundleId , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SO.OrderId  ORDER BY SO.OrderId ASC) AS Row#     
from SaleOrderLine SOL
join SaleOrder SO on SOL.OrderId = SO.OrderId
join BundleProduct BP on BP.ProductId = SOL.ProductId
join Bundle B on B.BundleId = BP.BundleId
) As Test

where Row# > 1
```

[Full Query here..](http://rextester.com/TKPA94291)

Comment: Your query would also return an order with multiple products of different bundles.